# Install of Datastax Community Edition failing

Tags: ubuntu, cassandra, datastax

On a Digital Ocean Droplet using Ubuntu 14.04 x64 I installed the DSC 2.0 package. The service does not stay started, service status returns `could not access pidfile for Cassandra`. No errors in log file. `ps aux | grep cassandra` returns nothing as well.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435749/cant-start-an-application-as-service-but-running-as-standalone-process-simply) suggests doing a `sudo chmod 750 /var/run/cassandra` or removing the folder. Neither works. I can briefly get the `status` command to read the pid if I do `chmod -R 777 /var/run/cassandra/` but that soon fails starts returning the `could not read...` error.

Steps (as root):

1. Installed Oracle 7 JDK ([instructions here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html))
2. Made sure JAVA+HOME & JRE_HOME were set ([instructions for 2 - 5 here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/install/installDeb_t.html))
3. Added Datastax repo to sources.list
4. Added repo key
5. `sudo apt-get update` & `sudo apt-get install dsc20`
6. `sudo service cassandra status` gets `could not access pidfile for Cassandra`
7. `nodetool status` gets `Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199': Connection refused`
8. `ps aux | grep cassandra` gets only the grep line returned

Comment: So it turns out the first level droplet from Digital Ocean does not have enough RAM for DSC. Even the second level is iffy

Comment: I've seen the same scenario. Cassandra will essentially silently fail in such low memory conditions, and won't write anything useful to the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, the smallest Digital Ocean droplet doesn't provide enough RAM for Cassandra to finish starting up. If you look at the log `/var/log/cassandra/system.log`, it will usually be cut off at some random point.

For any real development on Digital Ocean, I usually pick the 1 or 2GB RAM configurations.

Through some trial and error, you can manually lower the Cassandra memory usage to get it working. In the file `/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh` I set the following:

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="150M"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="40M"
```

In my tests that is low enough to let it run on a 512 MB environment. I'm not sure how usable it will be, but it will run :)